# Increase value of prices

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to make one simple "app". When user increase/decrease `ng-model="kilograms"`

I want to multiply the current price with "kilograms" and to change value in table.

I don't know how I can grab **product.price** in JS file.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/DenisLapi/pen/LkyRxW)

Comment: Please write all associated code here, do not link to external sites. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several places that can use fixes

1.You can use `ng-change` to track changes in your input, use that instead of `ng-click`.

```
<input type="number" ng-change="updateValue()" ng-model="kilograms"/>
```

2.The update function should not take a value, because you are updating the whole table instead of specific entry. That means you need to use a loop to update all entries, too.

```
$scope.updateValue = function () {
   angular.forEach($scope.products, function(item){
     item.totalPrice = item.price * $scope.kilograms;
   });
 }
```

3.You can't update your `price` so you lose track of your unit price, you'll need to hold it in other attribute, i.e `totalPrice`

4.You'll need to call the update function once during initialization, so you don't see an empty table on load.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xOdWOB

Comment: Maybe is a bit stupid question.. But how angularJS know what is 'item' is that index of array?

Comment: You mean what is the index of `item`? You can get that by the second parameter in the function `angular.forEach(array, function(item, index){ console.log(index); })`

Answer (score 2):

```
var app = angular.module("application", []);

  app.controller("filterCTRL", function($scope) {

     $scope.products = [
        {name:"Milk", price:100},
        {name:"Orange", price:120},  
        {name:"Farina", price:50}
     ];

     $scope.kilograms = 2;

     $scope.$watch('kilograms', function(newVal, oldVal) {
       if( newVal != oldVal) {
         $scope.products.forEach(function(product) {
            product.price *= newVal;
         });
       }
     });

     $scope.updateValue = function (product) {
       return product.price = product.price * $scope.kilograms;
     }
});
```

lcyool's answer also does work :)

Creating $watch and ng-change both will trigger a function whenever the value of the element changes. You can use this to detect the change, and multiple the value of kilogram and price and update it.

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply the price with the `kilograms` in the HTML itself and it will change the **product.price** when `kilograms` is changed.

```
<td>{{product.price * kilograms | currency:$:0}}</td>
```